# Forwarding a request for Azure App Service to Azure Blob storage

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I have a web site that is hosted as an Azure App Service. I want to have one directory of that service serve files that are managed by the site. I don't really want to store the files on the App Service as I'm worried they might get deleted during a redeployment. I was thinking I would just store the files in an Azure Storage Account. I can't however see a way of forwarding on the requests to the Storage Account.

So for example:

If I have a site at `example.com/` I want the file `example.com/form.aspx` to be served from my App Service, but I want to have everything in `example.com/File/` (e.g `example.com/File/File1.jpeg`) served from my Storage Account. I don't want to do a redirect because that would change the URL the user sees in their browser.

How would you set that up?

Comment: Not sure whether I understand the question. Perhaps you need ‘Azure Data Lake Gen 2’ which support hierarchical namespace to Blob storage.

Comment: You should be able to use IIS ARR URL Rewrite in the front-ends.  Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630536/rewriting-a-url-in-an-azure-web-app and https://www.solutionwave.net/2018/02/15/using-a-reverse-proxy-to-serve-azure-blobs-from-your-primary-domain/

Answer (score 1):

@Martin Brown, if you want the images to be served from your storage account there's nothing 'out of the box' that will do this for you I'm afraid; you'll have to write a controller endpoint which handles requests to `/File/{fileName}`, downloads the corresponding file into a stream in memory and then returns a `FileResult`.

Comment: This is what I thought, but it's hard to prove for certain that something doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can move all images to a static folder and do a rewrite to the images from Static Blob content as mentioned in this answer [Windows Azure Website and static html in Blob storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842249/windows-azure-website-and-static-html-in-blob-storage)